# Can't create flyout in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uielement, flyout

Adding a flyout seemed like a pretty straightforward task, but I can't seem to even initialize one on my app (which is based on a PivotControl app template for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight). When I attempt to do this:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
         <Flyout x:Key="MyFlyout"></Flyout>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I immediately get a blue squiggly line below *Flyout* saying "The name Flyout doesn't exist in the namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/clients/2007". What gives?

Answer (score 1):

`<Flyout>` is only available in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime (Silverlight is a no-go).  See the [MSDN Reference FlyOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx).

If you want something similar to a `<Flyout>` that would work for Silverlight, download and install the Windows Phone Toolkit -- NuGet or get it here : [The Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/)

Using the `<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>`

```
<container_ui>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>    
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>   
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="menu_1" Click="Click_Event"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="menu_2" Command="{Binding CommandBinding}"/>    
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>    
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</container_ui>
```

Comment: Okay, but the latest update for it came out in Aug 2013. You think it'll work with 8.1?

Comment: @Ali250 yeah, just install it using NuGet.  There is little difference between 8.1SL and 8.0SL.